# Python 3.6 - How Do I Format Variables and Literals In A .Write Statement?

Tags: python

... (Be advised the actual values in the data below are not static nor that important, but are only an example.)

Specifically, I am needing assistance on understanding what I did wrong with the format and syntax and what is the proper way. Anyway, here goes.

I need the following Python 3.6 code...

```
stella = open(stellocation + "\\scripts\\sh4.ssc",'w')
stella.write("core.setDate(\""+date+"T"+time+":00", "UTC""); ")\n)
stella.write("core.setObserverLocation("+longitude +", "+latitude+", 6, 0, "SH4 Navigation Point, ""+ ocean +", "earth")");
stella.close()
```

...to produce this text...

```
core.setDate("1943-01-01T10:01:00","UTC");
core.setObserverLocation(-161.605158333, 19.2008553333, 6, 0, "USS Perch (Pacific Ocean)", "Earth");
```

...I keep getting this error...

```
  File "C:\DAATAPOND\Python Scripts\SH4toStellarium.py", line 54
    stella.write("core.setDate(\""+date+"T"+time+":00"") ")\n)
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I have been researching and experimenting for three days without success. I have read and attempted to digest a number of websites on the ".write" function statement. They tended to be arcane and left me somewhat confused. I decided it was time to seek help. :)

Please let  me know if I can be of any assistance.

Take care,
Calvin

PS - This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please let me know if anything should be different.

Comment: `\n` should be inside the quoted string. And you have an extra `)`.

Comment: Also `;` needs to get in, as that would be the next error ;) line 55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an f-string to make variable substitution easier. And if you want to put literal double-quotes in the string, wrap it in single quotes so you don't need to escape them.

The syntax error is because you put `\n` outside the string and added an extra `)`.

```
stella.write(f'core.setDate("{date}T{time}:00","UTC");\n')
stella.write(f'core.setObserverLocation({longitude}, {latitude}, 6, 0, "SH4 Navigation Point, ({ocean})", "Earth");')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It fixed this error. I have some more issues I need to fix, but your response has given me some ideas to try.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:
`stella.write("core.setDate(\""+date+"T"+time+":00"") \n")`

**Where you went wrong**: You were using an extra bracket at the end of the above line and `\n` was outside the quoted string.

Comment: Thank you for responding and the heads-up.